# Ruby Paperclip Amazon S3 Bucket Connection refused - connect(2) for "s3-website-us-west-1" port 443

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to upload images using Amazon S3 into the bucket I created.  However, I keep getting an error message - Connection refused - connect(2) for "s3-website-us-west-1" port 443

I put this in the config/environments/production.rb file

```
    config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => 'mybucketname', #ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => 'myaccesskey'
    :secret_access_key => 'mysecretkey'
  }
```

This is what have in the initilizers paperclip.rb file

```
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = 'mybucketname.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com'
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-website-us-west-1'
```

I also set the IAM user to have AmazonS3FullAccess and AdministratorAccess as the Policy Permissions.  Thanks,

Comment: Don't think you want to set s3_host_name (although you may want to set the region in addition to bucket)

Comment: I was getting this error when I didn't have s3_host_name set - "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.”  I am following the instruction from the heroku website - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

I also tried adding the region, but get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website endpoints don't support https or uploads -- they're only for downloads.  You're looking for the REST endpoint, which should be `s3-eu-west-1`, assuming that's your bucket location, and possibly followed by `.amazonaws.com`, depending on what that library expects.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/MakingRequests.html#RequestEndpoints

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html